# Tkinter - A 'previous' button in a find window for text

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been developing an IDE. At this moment, I am trying to create a find window, which, as the name suggests, finds a text in a **tkinter.text** that the user has entered in an entry field. I am trying to make the find window contain a 'previous' button which gets the word that is present **before** the current selection and makes that word the new selection, but I'm not able to create a logic which may do the same.

I have already made a 'next' button which finds the word that is present in the tkinter.text after the current selection.

Here's some code which might help you understand my issue:

```
def find_function(event=None):
            global find_entry, idx, find_entry_stringvar
            idx = "1.0"
            find_window = tkinter.Toplevel(editing_area)
            def callback(var):
                global idx, find_entry_stringvar
                idx = "1.0"
                find_entry_stringvar = var.get()
            find_entry_stringvar.trace_add("write", lambda name, index, mode, find_entry_stringvar=find_entry_stringvar: callback(find_entry_stringvar))
            find_entry = tkinter.Entry(find_window, width=24, textvariable=find_entry_stringvar)
            def check_focus(event=None):
                editing_area.tag_remove("found", "1.0", "end")
            editing_area.bind("<FocusIn>", check_focus)
            find_window.bind("<FocusOut>", check_focus)
            find_entry.pack()
            find_entry.focus_force()
            previous_button = tkinter.Button(find_window, text="←", border=1, fg="white", bg="black", command=lambda: find_buttons_function(previous_or_next="previous"))
            previous_button.pack(side="left")
            find_window.bind("<Shift-Return>", lambda: find_buttons_function(previous_or_next="previous"))
            next_button = tkinter.Button(find_window, text="→", border=1, fg="white", bg="black", command=lambda: find_buttons_function(previous_or_next="next"))
            next_button.pack(side="right")
            find_window.bind("<Return>", lambda: find_buttons_function(previous_or_next="next"))
        def find_buttons_function(previous_or_next, event=None):
            global find_entry, idx, find_matches_found, find_to_find
            editing_area.tag_remove("found", "1.0", "end")
            find_to_find = find_entry_stringvar
            no_of_finds = 0
            if find_to_find:
                if previous_or_next == "previous":
                    pass
                        
                elif previous_or_next == "next":
                    match_in_whole_text = editing_area.search(find_to_find, "1.0", "end")
                    if match_in_whole_text:
                        find_matches_found = True
                    else:
                        find_matches_found = False
                    idx = editing_area.search(find_to_find, idx, "end")
                    if idx:
                        lastidx = f"{idx}+{len(find_to_find)}c"
                        editing_area.tag_add("found", idx, lastidx)
                        editing_area.tag_config("found", background="#8fa7cc")
                        editing_area.see(idx)
                        idx = lastidx
                        editing_area.mark_set("insert", idx)
                    else:
                        if find_matches_found == False:
                            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("No match found", f"No match for {find_to_find} was found")
                        else:
                            idx = "1.0"
                            find_buttons_function(previous_or_next="next")
```

And here's some logic upto which I could reach for the previous button's function (I have put `pass` in the previous code in there):

```
if previous_or_next == "previous":
                    i = 0
                    match_in_whole_text = editing_area.search(find_to_find, "1.0", "end")
                    if match_in_whole_text:
                        find_matches_found = True
                    else:
                        find_matches_found = False
                    idx = editing_area.search(find_to_find, "1.0", "end")
                    lastidx = f"{idx}+{len(find_to_find)}c"
                    if idx:
                        while idx:
                            lastidx = f"{idx}+{len(find_to_find)}c"
                            idx = editing_area.search(find_to_find, lastidx, "end")
                            no_of_finds += 1
                        idx = editing_area.search(find_to_find, "1.0", "end")
                        lastidx = f"{idx}+{len(find_to_find)}c"
                        while i < no_of_finds - 1:
                            lastidx = f"{idx}+{len(find_to_find)}c"
                            idx = editing_area.search(find_to_find, lastidx, "end")
                            i += 1
                        lastidx = f"{idx}+{len(find_to_find)}c"
                        editing_area.tag_add("found", idx, lastidx)
                        editing_area.tag_config("found", background="#8fa7cc")
                        editing_area.see(idx)
                        editing_area.mark_set("insert", idx)
                    else:
                        if find_matches_found == False:
                            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("No match found", f"No match for {find_to_find} was found")
```

I'm sorry for any inconvenience.

Any help would surely be appreciated.

Comment: The `search` method can search backwards from a point. Are you aware of that?

Comment: @Swagrim. Used a list to keep previous

Comment: @BryanOakley I tried using the ```search``` method by interchanging the parameters ```idx``` and ```end```, but then the returned idx is an empty string. Can you provide the code for searching backwards from a point?

Comment: @BryanOakley I tried adding a parameter called ```backwards=True``` but the result is something weird: It first selects the **last** find and then again on clicking, it selects the **first** find and keeps on doing this again and again.

Comment: *"I tried adding a parameter called backwards=True but the result is something weird"* Can you make a small code example which shows that behavior? I may forgot the give the last-found-position as and end index?

Comment: Look at [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/571e23d99157ed7ad67ca2334a396fc9ddbe07ec/Lib/idlelib/searchengine.py#L164). It's from `idlelib/searchengine.py`. It's the code that does the backwards searching in IDLE.

Comment: @tturbo I am sorry, but your words aren't clear. I couldn't understand.

Comment: @TheLizzard I tried it, but it's an oop code, so it wasn't helpful either. I also tried a lot to change the code as per my project, but in vain.

Comment: @Swagrim: Sorry i made a spelling error: "You maybe forgot to set the start/end index correctly". Can you show whats results are "weird"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I hope I understood your issue correctly. My solution implicates individual `tags` for each matching text element. Try to search for `spam`. Also the `previous` and `next` buttons are bound to the `left` and `right` arrows, but only in the TopLevel widget and this has to be selected each time. It might be nicer to implicate the search entry widget into the main window.
I based my code on an example from [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/search-string-in-text-using-python-tkinter/).

```
import tkinter as tkinter

def find_function():
    global find_entry, idx, find_entry_stringvar, idx_now, no_of_finds
    find_window = tkinter.Toplevel(editing_area)

    find_entry_stringvar = tkinter.StringVar()
    find_entry = tkinter.Entry(find_window, width=24, textvariable=find_entry_stringvar)
    find_entry.pack()
    find_entry.focus_force()

    find_window.bind("<Return>", find_first)

    previous_button = tkinter.Button(find_window, text="←", border=1, fg="white", bg="black", command=lambda: find_next_previous(previous_or_next="previous"))
    previous_button.pack(side="left")
    find_window.bind("<Left>", left)

    next_button = tkinter.Button(find_window, text="→", border=1, fg="white", bg="black", command=lambda: find_next_previous(previous_or_next="next"))
    next_button.pack(side="right")
    find_window.bind("<Right>", right)


def left(event):
    find_next_previous('previous')


def right(event):
    find_next_previous('next')


def find_first(event):
    global found_items, idx_now, no_of_finds

    for tag in text.tag_names():
        text.tag_delete(tag)

    s = find_entry_stringvar.get()

    if s:
        no_of_finds = 0
        idx = '1.0'
        while 1:
            idx = text.search(s, idx, nocase=1, stopindex='end')
            if not idx:
                break
            lastidx = '%s+%dc' % (idx, len(s))
            no_of_finds += 1
            text.tag_add('found' + str(no_of_finds), idx, lastidx)
            idx = lastidx
    text.tag_config('found1', foreground='red')
    idx_now = 1
    text.focus_set()


def find_next_previous(previous_or_next):
    global idx_now, no_of_finds
    text.tag_config('found' + str(idx_now), foreground='black')

    if no_of_finds == 1:
        print('No more hits!')

    if previous_or_next == "next":
        if idx_now < no_of_finds:
            idx_now += 1
        else:
            idx_now = 1
        text.tag_config('found' + str(idx_now), foreground='red')
        text.focus_set()

    elif previous_or_next == "previous":
        if idx_now > 1:
            idx_now -= 1
        else:
            idx_now = no_of_finds
        text.tag_config('found' + str(idx_now), foreground='red')
        text.focus_set()


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("700x500")
editing_area = tkinter.Frame(root).grid(row=0, column=0)


text = tkinter.Text(editing_area)
text.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

text.insert('end', 'hello world spam text python stackoverflow spamspam text')

btn1 = tkinter.Button(master=editing_area, text='find', command=find_function)
btn1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```